# How to access particular JSON data in this case?

Tags: json, python-2.7

I know i can retrieve total units like this in python using simplejson.

```
jsondata = json.loads(r.text)
jsondata['data']['total_units']
```

But how do i go on and fetch data of status field?

```
  {
status: 'ok',                                                                      
data: {
    total_units: 1,                                                               
    unit_info: [{
        type: 'car',                                                             
        status: 'Blue car',          
        id: '20513'
        }]
      }
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jsondata['data']['unit_info'][0]['status']
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to index the list in the 'unit_info' key in order to get at the dict inside it.